# Undefined variable: user_id in get_user_meta

Tags: customization, user-meta

I got the undefined variable : user_id when i use get_user_meta

```
$phone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone_no', true );
$icno = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'ic_no', true );
```

when i try put the above code below this line

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
```

no error occur but my value $phone and $icno become empty

This is my full code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Register
*/
get_header(); 
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined('ABSPATH')) exit;
?>
<html>
    

<body id="login-page" <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div class="container">
<div class="row register-page-container p-3 p-lg-5 mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center w-75 mx-auto">
<?php
global $wpdb, $user_ID;
    
//Check whether the user is already logged in 
if (!$user_ID) {
// Default page shows register form. 
// To show Login form set query variable action=login
$action = (isset($_GET['action']) ) ? $_GET['action'] : 0;
// Login Page
if ($action === "login") { ?>
<?php 
$login = (isset($_GET['login']) ) ? $_GET['login'] : 0;
if ( $login === "failed" ) {
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error"><strong>ERROR:</strong> Invalid username and/or password.</div>';
} elseif ( $login === "empty" ) {
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error"><strong>ERROR:</strong> Username and/or Password is empty.</div>';
} elseif ( $login === "false" ) {
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error"><strong>ERROR:</strong> You are logged out.</div>';
}
?>
<div class="col-md-5">
<?php 
$args = array(
'redirect' => home_url().'/login/', 
);
wp_login_form($args); ?>
<p class="text-center"><a class="mr-2" href="<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>">Register Now</a>
<span clas="mx-2">·</span><a class="ml-2" href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url( ); ?>" title="Lost Password">Lost Password?</a></p>
</div>
<?php
} else { // Register Page ?>

<?php if(get_option('users_can_register')) { ?>
<div class="col-md-5 manual-register-form">
<form action="" method="post"> 
<p> 
<label for="user_login">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Type your Username Here" class="register-input mb-4" value="<?php if( ! empty($username) ) echo $username; ?>" /><br />
</p>
<p> 
<label for="user_password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Type your Password Here" class="register-input mb-4" value="<?php if( ! empty($password) ) echo $password; ?>" /><br />
</p>
<p> 
<label for="user_email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Type your Email Here" class="register-input mb-4" value="<?php if( ! empty($email) ) echo $email; ?>" /> <br /> 
</p>
<p> 
<label for="phone_no">Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone_no" placeholder="Type your Phone Here" class="register-input mb-4" value="<?php if( ! empty($phone) ) echo $phone; ?>" /> <br /> 
</p>
<p> 
<label for="ic_no">IC No</label>
<input type="text" name="ic_no" placeholder="Type your IC No Here" class="register-input mb-4" value="<?php if( ! empty($icno) ) echo $icno; ?>" /> <br /> 
</p>
<input type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="mb-4" name="submit" value="SignUp" /> 
</form>
<p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Login Here</a></p>
</div>
<?php } else {
echo "Registration is currently disabled. Please try again later."; 
    
}
} ?>
<?php
if ( $_POST ) {
$error = 0;
    
$username = esc_sql($_REQUEST['username']); 
if ( empty($username) ) {
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error">User name should not be empty.</div>'; 
$error = 1;
}

$email = esc_sql($_REQUEST['email']);
if ( !preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/", $email) ) { 
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error">Please enter a valid email.</div>';
$error = 1;
}
    
$phone = esc_sql($_REQUEST['phone_no']);
if ( empty($phone) ) { 
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error">Please enter a valid phone.</div>';
$error = 1;
}
    
$error = 0; 
$icno = esc_sql($_REQUEST['ic_no']);
if ( empty($icno) ) { 
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error">Please enter a valid IC No.</div>';
$error = 1;
}   
    
if ( $error == 0 ) {
$password = esc_sql($_REQUEST['password']); 
if ( empty($password) ) {
echo '<div class="col-12 register-error">Password should not be empty.</div>'; 
$error = 1;
}
$phone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone_no', true );
$icno = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'ic_no', true );

$username  = $_POST['username'];
$password  = $_POST['password'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$icno   = $_POST['ic_no'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone_no'];

    $user_data = [
    'user_login' => $username,
    'user_pass'  => $password,
    'user_email'   => $email,

];
 
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone_no', $phone );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'ic_no', $icno ); 

// // success
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    echo 'User created: '. $user_id;
}   
 
 else {
 echo 'Registration error';
}
}
}
if ( $error != 2 ) { ?> 
<?php  }
} else { ?>
<p>You are logged in. Click <a href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>">here to go home</a></p>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is really, really no good idea to insert unfiltered or unsanitized values. You should validate the $_POST data before writing them to database.

Comment: From what I could see, `$user_id` is indeed not defined before those `get_user_meta()` calls. Only `$user_ID` that got defined earlier in your code.

Comment: ya $user_id and $user_ID is the problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

> I got the undefined variable : user_id when i use get_user_meta

This is because `$user_id` is empty and undefined, you need to give it a value, and that value needs to be the ID of a user.

> when i try put the above code below this line

> no error occur but my value $phone and $icno become empty

Yes, you gave `$user_id` a value so it worked. The reason phone and icno are empty is because there is no user meta for phone and icno. **The order you do things in matters.** Code is executed from the top of the file to the bottom.

You can't retrieve values before they are added, and you can't use variables before they are set.

2 final notes:

- indenting your code is important, especially if you share it with other people, and it eliminates an entire class of bugs
- `global $wpdb, $user_ID;` should be removed. The code never uses `$wpdb` and there is no `$user_ID` global variable unless `setup_userdata` is called.